# Dropdown menu not showing the correct table when opening

Tags: python, plotly-python

I've created a dropdown menu on Plotly (Python) for the user to select the table to be visible. Everything works fine, except for the fact that when I first open the HTML file, the dropdown menu shows the correct metric, but the wrong table. After I change the dropdown selection it works fine.

I have set the active parameter to 0, it shows the correct option on the dropdown, but the table showing when I open the file is always the last table that I've created.

I already tried to change the tables order, but it didn't work.

```
updatemenus = list([
    dict(active=0,
        x=0.16,
        y=0.823,
            dict(label = 'Gross Sales by Week',
                 method = 'update',
                 args = [{'visible': [True, False, False, 
                                    False, False, False,
                                    False, False, False,
                                    False, False, False,
                                    False, False, False,
                                    True]},
]),
```

I expect the file to show the correct table when first opened.

Comment: Hi, try to make a Minimum and Complete Working Example. That'll help to get answers.

Comment: I found out the problem, I had to add visible=False to all go.Table to show only one on the first load.